Setting "periodic=True" unexpectedly wraps latitude (xesmf regridder)?
I'm currently working on a project that involves regridding Northern Hemisphere data from various types of (rectilinear) grids to a common grid. Some of the grids are coarser than the target, while some are higher resolution, and the bounds (min/max latitude) are not always consistent.
I was surprised to see a certain kind of behaviour near the 90degreeN edge of the domain for a bilinear regridding of temperature when I applied this method in my workflow. I have tried to dig into it, but am wondering what others think of this.
To demonstrate the issue, I generate and plot some synthetic data on a lat-lon grid.

Next, I build a target dataset with a finer resolution and slightly greater set of latitude bounds. I also slightly offset the longitudes. Then, I build a regridder object and toggle the "periodic" and "unmapped_to_nan" arguments to illustrate the issue I'm seeing through four cases.

By default (top left), I see a band of zeros along the northern, eastern, and southern edges of the domain. When I set "unmapped_to_nan=True" (top right), it becomes clear that all of those zeros have appeared because the target grid has points outside the domain of the original dataset. This seems reasonable to me.
Next, I set periodic=True (second row), which is what I would be tempted to do when working with data extending around the earth. The eastern edge of the domain fills in as I might expect. This is because the periodic longitude dimension enables us to fill in points that are "outside" the domain of the original dataset. The northern and southern edges of the domain are zero again, presumably because they are outside the domain. However, when I set "unmapped_to_nan=True", I actually see that the points along the northern edge of the domain are not outside the domain. Again, this makes sense, but I don't understand how those points are filled.
(And I can avoid this issue by using another regridding method.)

Where are the zero values coming from?
Is this reasonable behaviour? Maybe I have applied periodic=True incorrectly or maybe I need to be more careful about how my grids overlap.
I get the same issue if I have a grid that varies east-to-west (see below). Why does a repeated value appear, and not something that also varies east-to-west?
This is not resolved by setting an extrapolation method (nearest_s2d or inverse_dist), but I think that's aligned with the finding that the northern edge of the target domain is not being seen as "outside" the original domain.


Code to reproduce:
import xarray as xr
import xesmf as xe
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Sample data that only varies north-to-south 
### (converges to the same value at north pole and periodic in lon)
ds = xr.DataArray(data = np.arange(10, 89, dtype='float').repeat(12).reshape(-1,12), 
                  dims=['lat','lon'],
                  coords={'lat': ('lat', np.arange(10.5, 89.5)),
                          'lon': ('lon', np.arange(-180, 180, 30))}).to_dataset(name='test_vals')
ds = ds.cf.guess_coord_axis().cf.add_bounds(('lat', 'lon'))

### Sample target grid
target_ds = xr.DataArray(dims=['lat','lon'],
                         coords={'lat': ('lat', np.arange(2/3, 90, 1/3)),
                                 'lon': ('lon', np.arange(-180+0.5, 180+0.5, 30))}).to_dataset(name='test_vals')

### Plot initial data
ds.test_vals.plot(levels=np.arange(0, 90, 5))
plt.title('Original Data')
plt.show()

### Toggle settings and plot each version w/ same levels, add titles
n=0
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,8), nrows=2, ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'hspace':0.4, 'wspace':0.4},sharey=True)
for periodic in [False, True]:
    for unmapped_to_nan in [False, True]:

        regridder = xe.Regridder(ds, target_ds, 'bilinear', periodic=periodic, unmapped_to_nan=unmapped_to_nan)
        rg_data = regridder(ds, keep_attrs=True)

        levs = rg_data.test_vals.plot(ax=axs[n//2, n%2], levels=np.arange(0, 90, 5), add_colorbar=False)
        axs[n//2, n%2].set_title(['Periodic' if periodic else 'Not Periodic'][0] + ' + ' + ['Unmapped -> Nan' if unmapped_to_nan else 'Unmapped -> Zero'][0], fontsize='small')
        n+=1

fig.suptitle('Regridded Data (various settings)')
plt.show()

